# How to successfully deploy a web map application built with Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS on local server?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

Following some research, I have built a web map application using web app builder for ArcGIS using my ArcGIS Onlince (AGOL) account which runs properly. With aims to extend some functionalities and themes of the application, I downloaded the app and have inserted in my Internet Information Services (IIS) - C:\inetpub\wwwroot of my pc.

when I run the .index file, it does not yield any results. It shows loading sign but never fully loads.

When I use the link; "http://"machinename"/"name of application"/ it equally does not work. It start to load and later shows "this page cannot load" check your proxy settings. So far from my findings it appears it is proxy settings which is the issue but I am unable to resolve it at this level.

Is there another simple or good means by which I can deploy my application on my PC? What are the steps or where is a link to where I can research this further?

Comment: Are there any message in the console? And take a look at the [steps required](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/xt-deploy-app.htm) to deploy a site/